# linux environment variables setting disappear

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I've got a following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYCACHED_HOST='localhost'
export PYCACHED_PORT=8001
echo "PyCached environment variables set to: PYCACHED_HOST=`echo $PYCACHED_HOST`, PYCACHED_PORT=`echo $PYCACHED_PORT`"
```

when I run it, following output is printed:

```
PyCached environment variables set to: PYCACHED_HOST=localhost, PYCACHED_PORT=8001
```

and when I run the same echo line again:

```
echo "PyCached environment variables set to: PYCACHED_HOST=`echo $PYCACHED_HOST`, PYCACHED_PORT=`echo $PYCACHED_PORT`"
```

I get:

```
PyCached environment variables set to: PYCACHED_HOST=, PYCACHED_PORT=
```

I know that env vars are set for the script context, but what can I do to make them available after the script execution is over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `what can I do to make them available after the script execution is over?`

Run your script as;

```
source ./script.sh
```

OR

```
. ./script.sh
```

This will run your script in current shell without creating a new process hence env variables will be available in current shell after script is over.

Comment: This is the solution, works perfectly! PS is there any semantic difference between `source` and additional dot syntax? Is it totally the same?

Comment: Yes they both are actually same. dot is short cut syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the env variables every now and then, you may set them in `.bashrc` file. It is a hidden file, generally found in home directory. It is executed before opening any shell prompt.